# iPhone Development Memory Warnings

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, memory, memory-leaks

I know people here can help me with my problem in memory warnings on my app. I have multiple objects added to my Nib file, connected them to multiple IBOutlets and release these outlets on my viewDidUnload and dealloc method, I also set them to nil, but it still keeps on crashing after the "Received Memory Warning = Level 1" error message. I used NWPickerField for my objects in Nib files.

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/nwpickerfield

I just hope anyone here have tried using this :) thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're crashing when you receive the memory warning, that usually means that something gets deallocated, but it's pointer isn't set to nil, you try to access it, and Crash!

Errors like this can be hard to track down. A few types:
You can play around with XCode instruments (using Build&Profile in XCode 4) - specifically the Zombies one, which 'keeps dead objects around (as Zombies)', but let's you know when they get accessed.
Another useful one is a watchpoint. Once the simulator is running, right click a variable in console, and say 'Watch this address'. Then any line of code that causes a change to that memory location will cause a breakpoint when it occurs.
Another thing to try is just to run through all your ivars, inits, and deallocs, and make sure you really did get every case.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question.

> I also set them to nil,

Do the proper memory clean up. by first calling `release` function or `delete` operator then assign the object with `nil`.

Comment: “I … release these outlets on my viewDidUnload and dealloc method, I also set them to nil,”

Comment: @Peter Hosey : Could not get you here ?

Comment: The questioner is already releasing the objects. (Are you suspecting that they're assigning `nil` before sending the `release` message? If so, that wasn't clear in your answer.)